# How do I modify this code to add up all the numbers in the "Numbers.txt" file and display their sum?

Tags: c++

How do I modify this code to add up all the numbers in the "Numbers.txt" file and display their sum?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int num,
        total;

    inFile.open("Numbers.txt");

    while (inFile >> num)
    {
        cout << num << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to do this on your own?

Comment: You need to initialize total, then add each new value of num to it.  I like that you are echoing the input.

Comment: @bigZigZag So show what you have done and tell us what doesn't work as expected. 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried while (inFile >> num)
 {
  total += num
  cout << total << endl;
 }

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot to add numbers between each other

Try this code:

```
  ifstream inFile;
  int numb, total = 0;

  inFile.open("Numbers.txt");

  while (inFile >> numb)
    {
      total += numb;
    }
   cout << total << endl;

  inFile.close();
  return 0;
```

Comment: When I tried the same thing but kept cout << total << endl; inside the while loop it didn't work. Can you explain why?